# how to toast message inside the filtering method?

Tags: android, android-toast

Interface:-

[image]

I want to make a toast message, if user did not choose any subject, it will toast message "Please choose subject". There is no error, the issue was I dont know where to put the coding to display the toast message when needed.

Coding:-

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(FilterTuitionCentreActivity.this, R.raw.soundeffect1);

    if (v == filterButton) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
        filterBtnFlag = true;
        if(spLocation.getSelectedItem() == null){
            return;
        }

        /*if(!(spSubject.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Subject")
                || spSubject.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Choose Subject"))){
            Toast.makeText(FilterTuitionCentreActivity.this, "Please choose subject.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }*/

        else {
            loadFilteredInstitutesList("Advertisement");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem with your code is it showing any error?

Comment: Re-edit the question..

Answer (score 0):

You need a move that validation logic up and return without go further if any validation fails.

```
            @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {

      //add your spinner validity checking here     

        if(!(spSubject.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Subject")
                                || 

spSubject.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Choose Subject"))){
                        Toast.makeText(FilterTuitionCentreActivity.this, "Please choose subject.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               return;
                    }

                final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(FilterTuitionCentreActivity.

        this, R.raw.soundeffect1);

                if (v == filterButton) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    filterBtnFlag = true;
                    if(spLocation.getSelectedItem() == null){
                        return;
                    }


                 loadFilteredInstitutesList("Advertisement");


                }
            }
```